# Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (making a list for common values)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

For example, I have two dicts.

```
A = {'a':1, 'b':10, 'c':2}
B = {'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':10}
```

I want a result like this:

```
{'a':1, 'b': [10, 3], 'c':[2, 4], 'd':10}
```

If a key appears in both the dicts, I want to list of both the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make *all* values lists:

```
{k: filter(None, [A.get(k), B.get(k)]) for k in A.viewkeys() | B}
```

using [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

Demo:

```
>>> A = {'a':1, 'b':10, 'c':2}
>>> B = {'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':10}
>>> {k: filter(None, [A.get(k), B.get(k)]) for k in A.viewkeys() | B}
{'a': [1], 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [10, 3], 'd': [10]}
```

This at least keeps your value types consistent.

To produce your output, you need to use the set intersection and symmetric differences between the two dictionaries:

```
dict({k: [A[k], B[k]] for k in A.viewkeys() & B},
     **{k: A.get(k, B.get(k)) for k in A.viewkeys() ^ B})
```

Demo:

```
>>> dict({k: [A[k], B[k]] for k in A.viewkeys() & B},
...      **{k: A.get(k, B.get(k)) for k in A.viewkeys() ^ B})
{'a': 1, 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [10, 3], 'd': 10}
```

In Python 3, `dict.keys()` is a dictionary view, so you can just replace all `.viewkeys()` calls with `.keys()` to get the same functionality there.

Comment: @thefourtheye: My version only calls `.get()` once, but won't indeed work for `A[k] = 0`... oops.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Both of them are correct. 1) If we do `A.get(k, B.get(k))`, we unconditionally execute `get` on both of them, your original version can short circuit. 2) Also, your point about Non-Truthy values is valid. +1 :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: no, my version was incorrect; `A[k] = 0`, no such key in `B` results in `None` being used for the output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Correct, that is what I meant by *your point about Non-Truthy values is valid*. Sorry it was not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

I would second the notion of Martijn Pieters that you problably want to have the same type for all the values in your result dict.

To give a second option:

you could also use the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to achieve your result quite intuitively.

a defaultdict is like a dict, but it has a default constructor that is called if the key doesn't exist yet.

so you would go:

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = {'a':1, 'b':10, 'c':2}
B = {'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':10}

result = defaultdict(list)

for d in [A, B]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k].append(v)
```

then in a later stage you still easily add more values to your result.

you can also switch to

```
defaultdict(set)
```

if you don't want duplicate values